# libmpg123 force floating point output when I read mp3 with integer encoding

Tags: c++, mp3

I use libsndfile to read audio files but MP3 isn't available.

So, I want to use libmp123 to read mp3 files.

I found easily how to read a "short int" encoding file and then convert datas read to floating point [-1.0 ... 1.0].

My question is: "libmp123 can do this automatically like libsndfile?"

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at the [example program](https://www.mpg123.de/api/mpg123__to__out123_8c_source.shtml)?
You can use `mpg123_format_none` to clear the list of allowed format/encoding pairs and then use `mpg123_format` to add new format/encoding pairs that only contain the encoding you want (MPG123_ENC_FLOAT_32, for example).

Answer (score 0):

It does work for me.

I use libmp123 inside my own program.

I wish to load mp3 datas as float but with, for example, a mp3 'short int' encoded.

```
int err;
err = mpg123_format_none(m_handle);
std::cout << err << std::endl;
err = mpg123_format(m_handle,m_rate,m_channels, MPG123_ENC_FLOAT_32);
std::cout << err << std::endl;

... 
if (mpg123_read(m_handle,
               (unsigned char*)titi,
               nb_framesToRead*mpg123_encsize(m_encoding),
               &nb_framesRead) != MPG123_OK) {
        std::cerr << mpg123_strerror(m_handle);
}
```

titi is a preallocated float table.

m_encoding = 208(SIGNED_16)

To sum up, I wish to have an equivalent to "sf_readf_float" http://www.mega-nerd.com/libsndfile/api.html#readf

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
  int ret;
  mpg123_handle *m = mpg123_new(NULL, &ret);
  mpg123_param(m, MPG123_ADD_FLAGS, MPG123_FORCE_FLOAT, 0.);
```